# double integral with singularity (not exactly singularity)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, singularity, singular-integrals

I'd like to solve $\iint_R \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}dA$, where $R=\{ (x,y) : x\ge0, y\ge 0, x^2+y^2 \le 4\}.$

I'm wondering if the following calculation is true:
$$
\begin{split}
\iint_R \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}dA
  &=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^2
      \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{r \sin \theta}{r\cos\theta}\right)rdrd\theta\\
  &=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^2 \tan^{-1}(\tan\theta)rdrd\theta\\
  &=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^2\theta rdrd\theta\\
  &=\frac{\pi^2}{4}
\end{split}
$$

It might be true, but I don't think it is a rigid proof.
Apparently, $\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}$ is not defined for $x=0,$ but since $\lim_{x \to +0} \frac{y}{x} \to \infty$, we may extend or regard $\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $x=0.$

Please let me know if you have any comments for this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter what value you set for $x=0$, if you prefer, you can calculate the integral on $\tilde{R} = \{(x,y) : x > 0, y\geq 0, x^2 + y^2 \leq 4 \}$

Comment: @Tryss  Thanks for your answer. Is it also okay to use polar coordinates to calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're noticing is that the integral is improper when $x=0$. 
This translates to it being improper at $\theta=\pi/2$ in polar coordinates. So it's slightly better to include the limits.

$$
\begin{split}
\iint_R \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}dA
&=\int_0^2\int_0^\sqrt{4-x^2}\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}\,dy\,dx\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0^+}\int_a^2\int_0^\sqrt{4-x^2}\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}\,dy\,dx\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0^+}\int_0^{\alpha(a)}\int_{a^2\sec\theta}^2\tan^{-1} \frac{r\sin\theta}{r\cos\theta}\,r\,dr\,d\theta\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0^+}\int_0^{\alpha(a)}\int_{a\sec\theta}^2 \theta r\,dr\,d\theta\\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0^+}\int_0^{\alpha(a)} 2\theta-\frac{a^2}{2}\theta \sec^2(\theta)\, d\theta\\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0^+} \theta^2 |_0^{\alpha(a)}-\frac{a^2}{2}\left[\ln\left|\cos\theta\right|-\theta\tan\theta\right]_0^{\alpha(a)}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{4}
\end{split}
$$

Note $x=a$ under the change of coordinates is $r\cos \theta=a$ so $r=a\sec\theta$. Also define the angle to the point $(a,\sqrt{4-a^2})$ to be $\alpha(a)$ for all $a>0$ that is $\alpha(a)=\tan^{-1}\sqrt{4/a^2-1}$.

First part simply becomes $\lim_{a\to 0^+} (\tan^{-1}\sqrt{4/a^2-1})^2=(\lim_{x\to\infty}\tan^{-1}(x))^2=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2$ the right hand part is zero. Here are some notes on how to see that

$$\begin{split}
\lim_{a\to 0^+}a^2\alpha(a)\tan(\alpha(a)) &=
\lim_{a\to 0^+}a^2\sqrt{4/a^2-1}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{4/a^2-1}\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0^+}a\sqrt{4-a^2}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{4/a^2-1}\\
&=(0)(2)\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0
\end{split}$$

$$\begin{split}
\lim_{a\to 0^+}a^2\ln\left|\cos\alpha(a)\right|&=
\lim_{a\to 0^+}a^2\ln\left|\frac{a^2}{4}\right|\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0^+}\frac{\ln\left|\frac{a^2}{4}\right|}{a^{-2}}\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0^+}-a^2=0
\end{split}$$

where the last step is by L'Hopital's rule

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems good, but it is not obvious the third equality true in your answer.

Comment: Well what level of resolution do you want? The intuitive approach is to draw the region and see that the line $x=0$ corresponds to the line $\theta = \pi/2$ and approaching from the right from $x$ is the same as approaching from the left for $\theta$. If you want a 100% rigorous proof there's a bit more work to do, but the intuition should come first.

Comment: Intuitively, it would be true, and I agree with you as my question. I’d like to know a rigorous proof of it in detail. Would you give it to me?

Comment: Okay here's a little bit more truthful of a statement. Let me know if you need more detail :)